# Moment js cree que las 12 pm son las 12 am

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Me di cuenta de que moment js tiene un error extraño, si coloco en un campo de tiempo de 24 horas las 12 pm (Es decir las 12:00)... moment js cree que son las 12 am como si colocara las 00 am

Esto usando la version 2.8.1

Esta es la fecha en la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que sepan que no es la base datos, aqui hay un ejemplo con 00:00 AM, para que sepan que no son lo mismo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de moment js

```
   var idAcceso = $('#Id_acceso').val();

    datos= JSON.stringify(valor);

    htmlSemana="<tr>";

    //valida si la clase esta activa
    if(valor[0][18] == "Si"){
        moment(valor[0][10],'h:m a').format('h:m a')
        htmlSemana+=`
        <td>${moment(valor[0][6],'h:mm a').format('h:mm a')} ${moment(valor[0][7],'h:mm a').format('h:mm a')}</td>
```

Si preguntan, los datos estan viniendo en formato de 24 horas, confirmado por console.log

Así es como moment js los esta poniendo, como ven en Evolution Air (teen)... este cree que las 12:00 son las 12:00 AM, pero 00:00 si lo pone como 12:00 AM como debe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué tiene valor[0][10]?

Comment: No entiendo, que quieres formatear. Esto `00:00:00`?

Comment: Incluye un ejemplo reproduciendo el error.

Comment: Puse una imagen del error ocurriendo. En la tercera imagen, el primer Evolution Air Teen debe tener como hora 12 PM (12:00) pero cree que son las 12 AM (00:00), el segundo Evolution Air Teen debe tener como hora las 12 AM (00:00) y ahí si lo pone bien

Comment: valor [0][10] es el valor de la hora actual al registrarse. El problema está en valor [0][6] y [0][7] que son la hora de inicio y final de la clase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el formato que le estas indicando a `momentjs` para interpretar (*parsear*) las horas.

En la primer imagen se puede ver que la `hora_inicio` es igual a `12:00:00` y el formato de esta **no corresponde** a `H:mm a`.

### Solución:

Para que `momentjs` interprete correctamente las fechas, necesitas usar el formato `H:m:s`.

#### Demo:

```js
console.log('FORMATO ERRONEO:', moment('12:00:00','h:mm a').format('h:mm a'));
console.log('FORMATO CORRECTO:', moment('12:00:00','H:m:s').format('h:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.1/moment.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

Referencia:

- [Momentjs - Parse > String + format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)